# Access denied in Drush but granted in GUI

Tags: database, drush, 9, installation

I am trying to install Drupal on a CentOS based *shared server environment* ([namecheap.com](https://namecheap.com)) with mysql, ssh and Composer.

I have created a database username and a database with the same name and a password and granted all user privileges.

I ran:

```shell
cd WEB_APPLICATION_ROOT
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
cd WEB_APPLICATION_DIR_NAME
composer require drush/drush
vendor/bin/drush site:install
```

I prompted:

```
 Database name [drupal]:
 > DB_NAME

 Database driver [mysql]:
 > DB_NAME

 Database username [drupal]:
 > DB_NAME

 Database password [drupal]:
 > DB_PASSWORD

 Database host [127.0.0.1]:
 > 127.0.0.1

 Database port [3306]:
 > 3306

 [warning] Program UNKNOWN not found. Proceed if you have already created or emptied the Drupal database.

 > You are about to:
 * Create a sites/default/settings.php file

 Do you want to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > yes
```

### Ouput

> [notice] Starting Drupal installation. This takes a while.
> [notice] Performed install task: install_select_language
> [notice] Performed install task: install_select_profile
> [notice] Performed install task: install_load_profile
> [notice] Performed install task: install_verify_requirements

> In install.core.inc line 971:

> Database name field is required.
> Database username field is required.
> Resolve all issues below to continue the installation. For help configuring your database server, see the [installation handbook](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install%0A), or contact your hosting provider.
>
> - Failed to connect to your database server. The server repor
>   ts the following message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'hanekudai'@'localhost' (using passw
>   ord: NO).
>
>   - Is the database server running?
>   - Does the database exist or does the database user have sufficient privileges to create the
>     database?
>   - Have you entered the correct database name?
>   - Have you entered the correct username and password?
>   - Have you entered the
>     correct database hostname and port number?

### GUI

when I went to `example.com/web/` and used the GUI installation with the exact same DB credentials, I have installed Drupal successfully.

### My question

What is the problem in Drush installation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138827/discussion-on-question-by-houdy-drush-access-denied-for-user-in-installation).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In

```
 Database driver [mysql]:
 > DB_NAME
```

I should have prompted

```
 Database driver [mysql]:
 > mysql
```

Then the installation finished without error.